# How can I remove the "reblogged from" link above posts I reblogged on Tumblr?

Tags: themes, tumblr

I have a bit of a pesky little issue that I know has a simple solution, but that I am not aware of.....yet.

Above the text in each post is a link leading to the person's blog of whom I reblogged that post from with a colon next to it. I want to get rid of this because it looks strange with my theme and it's also unnecessary.

If anyone could either tell me how to get rid of it, OR how to format it better so that it doesn't look like just one line of random text above the posts (maybe to where I can move it to the left or something), that would be awesome.

Here's the complete markup of my theme:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>{Title}{block:PostTitle}: {PostTitle}{/block:PostTitle}</title>
    {block:Description}
    <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}">
    {/block:Description}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- Tumblr Theme configuration -->
    <meta name="color:Background" content="#FFFFFF"/>
    <meta name="color:Link" content="#0000FF"/>
    <meta name="color:Link Hover" content="#FF0000"/>
    <meta name="color:Link Visited" content="#800080"/>

    <meta name="font:Site Font" content=""/>

    <meta name="text:Footer Text" content=""/>
    <meta name="text:Google Analytics ID" content=""/>

    <meta name="image:Header" content=""/>

    <meta name="if:Show Archive" content="1"/>
    <meta name="if:Show RSS" content="0"/>
    <meta name="if:Show Search" content="0"/>

    <meta name="if:Use Time Ago" content="1"/>
    <meta name="if:Use HighRes Photos" content="1"/>
    <meta name="if:Use Number Pagination" content="1"/>

    <!-- END Tumblr Theme configuration -->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{PortraitURL-128}">
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.github.com/wxrod/Tumblr-HTML5-Blank-Theme/master/css/normalize.min.css">

    <script src="https://raw.github.com/wxrod/Tumblr-HTML5-Blank-Theme/master/js/vendor/modernizr.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

/* THE BASICS */

body {
    background-color: #222;
    background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/ff3ukto/rAYmq57vt/hd_2ac77715bdfbaf4f407dbec9d5d75605.jpg');
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 11px;
}

a { 
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 8pt;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #8b1f2e;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

a:hover{ 
    color: #b61a30; 
}

i {
    color: #fff;
}

h1 {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #e0d4a8;
    border-bottom: solid 5px #d7ca98;
    padding-left: 12px;
}


/*POSTS*/

#content {
    color: #c4c4c4;
    background-color: #131312;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 65%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
}

.post {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #212121;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}


/*SIDEBAR*/

.sidebar {
    background-color: #ede6cc;
    text-align: justify;
    position: fixed;
    top: 25%;
    left: 73%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 10px;
}

.sidebar:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.pagination {
    font-color: #222;
}

/*NAV*/

#nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 21%;
    width: 89%;
    background-color: #4addae;
    margin-left: 5%;
    opacity: 0.9;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}

#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #222;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

#nav a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #e8d79a;
    border-bottom: 3px #222 solid;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}

/*TAGS*/

ul {
    list-style: lower-roman;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
}

ul li {
    list-style: lower-roman;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
     width: 500px;
}

ul.tags {
    list-style: lower-roman;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}

ul.tags li {
display: inline;
list-style: lower-roman;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

ul.tags li:after {
content: ", ";
color: #aaa;
list-style-type: lower-roman;
}

ul.tags li:last-child:after {
content: "";
list-style-type: lower-roman;
}

img.icon {
    vertical-align:text-top;
    float: right;
    padding: 2px;
}

/*IMAGE SIZE*/

.photoset {
    -webkit-transition: all .40s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .40s linear;
    -o-transition: all .40s linear;
    transition: all .40s linear;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.photoset:hover {
 -webkit-transition: all .40s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .40s linear;
    -o-transition: all .40s linear;
    transition: all .40s linear;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.photo {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
}

.photo .img {
    float: inherit;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.photo img {
    border: 7px #272727 solid;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all .40s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .40s linear;
    -o-transition: all .40s linear;
    transition: all .40s linear;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.photo img:hover {
   border: 7px #121212 solid;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all .40s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .40s linear;
    -o-transition: all .40s linear;
    transition: all .40s linear;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

/*DATE*/

.date {
  font-size:10px;
  color: #d77159;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana;
}

.jump_page {
padding: 4px 8px;
border: 2px solid #cce45e;
background-color: #ffffff;
color:#585858;
font-family:century gothic;
font-size:11px;
text-decoration:none;
}

.current_page, .jump_page:hover {
padding: 4px 8px;
border: 2px solid #b2c750;
background-color: #cce45e;
color: #ffffff;
font-family:century gothic;
font-size:11px;
text-decoration:none;
}

/* BLOCKQUOTE */

blockquote {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
    color: #353535;
    border-left: 2px #292929 solid;
    border-right: 2px #292929 solid;
}
      {CustomCSS}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <p class="chromeframe">You are using an outdated browser. <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade your browser today</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install Google Chrome Frame</a> to better experience this site.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <div id="wrapper">
      <!--PAGE HEADER ******************************************************************* -->
      <header>
      <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/ff3ukto/JKomqv42k/waovntgbanner.jpg" style="position: absolute; margin-left: 5%; top: 0%;">
        {block:IfHeaderImage}
          <div id="logo"><a href="/"><img src="{image:Header}"/></a></div>
        {/block:IfHeaderImage}
    <div class="sidebar">
        {block:Description}
          <p id="description">{Description}</p>
        {/block:Description}
        <div class="pagination">
{block:PreviousPage}<a href="{PreviousPage}">« </a>{/block:PreviousPage}
{block:NextPage}<a href="{NextPage}"> »</a>{/block:NextPage}
</div>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <a href="https://www.etsy.com/shop/weareonly">etsy shop</a>
            <a href="http://weareonly.tictail.com/">tictail shop</a>
            <a href="http://instagram.com/weareonly">instagram</a>
            <a href="http://www.weareonlyvntg.tumblr.com/contact">contact</a>
            <a href="http://www.weareonlyvntg.tumblr.com/tags">tags</a>
        </div>      
      </header>
      <!--PAGE LOOP ******************************************************************* -->
    <center><div id="content">
      <div id="main" role="main">
        {block:Posts}
        <title>{Title} - {block:PostTitle}{PostTitle}{/block:PostTitle}</title>
{block:HasTags}{/block:HasTags}
        {block:Text}
          <article class="post text">
            {block:Title}
            <header>
              <h2 class="entry-title">{Title}</h2>
            </header>
            {/block:Title}
            <p>
              {Body}
            </p>
        {/block:Text}

        <center>{block:Photo}
          <article class="post photo">
            <figure>
              {LinkOpenTag}
                {block:IfUseHighResPhotos}
                  <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />
                {/block:IfUseHighResPhotos}
                {block:IfNotUseHighResPhotos}
                  <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />
                {/block:IfNotUseHighResPhotos}
              {LinkCloseTag}

              {block:IfNotUseHighResPhotos}
                {block:HighRes}
                <a class="high-res" href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}">High-Res</a>
                {/block:HighRes}
              {/block:IfNotUseHighResPhotos}

              {block:Caption}
                <figcaption>
                  {Caption}
                </figcaption>
              {/block:Caption}
            </figure>
        {/block:Photo}</center>

        {block:Photoset}
          <article class="post photoset">
            <figure>
              {Photoset-500}
              {block:Caption}
                <figcaption>
                  {Caption}
                </figcaption>
              {/block:Caption}
            </figure>
        {/block:Photoset}

        {block:Quote}
          <article class="post quote">
            <blockquote>{Quote}</blockquote>
            {block:Source}
              <footer>{Source}</footer>
            {/block:Source}
        {/block:Quote}

        {block:Link}
          <article class="post link">
            <header>
              <h2>
                <a href="{URL}" {Target}>{Name}</a>
              </h2>
            </header> 
            {block:Description}
            <p> {Description} </p>
            {/block:Description}
        {/block:Link}

        {block:Chat}
          <article class="post chat">
            {block:Title}
            <header>
              <h2>{Title}</h2>
            </header>
            {/block:Title}
            <dialog>
              {block:Lines}
                {block:Label}
                  <dt class="{Alt} {UserNumber}">
                    {Label}
                  </dt>
                {/block:Label}
                <dd> {Line} </dd>
              {/block:Lines}
            </dialog>
        {/block:Chat}

        {block:Audio}
          <article class="post audio">
            <header>
              <h2>
                {block:Artist}
                  {Artist}
                {/block:Artist}

                {block:TrackName}
                  {TrackName}
                {/block:TrackName}
              </h2>
            </header>
            <figure>
              {block:AlbumArt}
                <img src="{AlbumArtURL}"/>
              {/block:AlbumArt}

              {block:AudioPlayer}
                {AudioPlayer}
              {/block:AudioPlayer} 

              {block:Caption}
                <figcaption>
                  {Caption}
                </figcaption>
              {/block:Caption}
            </figure>
        {/block:Audio}

        {block:Video}
          <article class="post video">
            <figure>
              {Video-500}
              {block:Caption}
                <figcaption>
                  {Caption}
                </figcaption>
              {/block:Caption}
            </figure>
        {/block:Video}

        {block:Answer}
          <article class="post answer">
            <dialog>
              <dt><img src="{AskerPortraitURL-16}"> {lang:Asker asked 2}: </dt>
              <dd>{Question}</dd>

              <dd>{Answer}</dd>
            </dialog>
        {/block:Answer}

            <footer>
            {block:RebloggedFrom}
                source / <a href="{ReblogRootURL}" title="{ReblogRootTitle}">{ReblogRootName}</a>
            {/block:RebloggedFrom}

              {block:NoteCount}
                <div class="notes">notes / <a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCount}</a></div>
              {/block:NoteCount}

              {block:HasTags} 
                <ul>
                  {block:Tags}
                  <li><a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a></li>
                  {/block:Tags}
                </ul>
              {/block:HasTags}

             <div class="date">
             {block:Date}
              <time datetime="{TimeAgo}">
                <a href="{Permalink}">
                  {block:IfUseTimeAgo}
                    {TimeAgo}
                  {/block:IfUseTimeAgo}

                 {block:IfNotUseTimeAgo}
                 <br>{TimeAgo}
                 {/block:IfNotUseTimeAgo}
                </a>
              </time>
              {/block:Date}
              </div>

              {block:PermalinkPage}
                {block:PostNotes}<div>{PostNotes-16}</div>{/block:PostNotes}
              {/block:PermalinkPage}   
            </footer>
          </article>
        {/block:Posts}
      </div>
    </div></center>
      <!--PAGE FOOTER ******************************************************************* -->
      <footer>
      </footer>
    </div>
    {block:IfGoogleAnalyticsID}    
    <script>
      var _gaq=[['_setAccount','{text:Google Analytics ID}'],['_trackPageview']];
      (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
    </script>
    {/block:IfGoogleAnalyticsID}    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove anything that looks like this:

```
{block:RebloggedFrom}
   . . .
{/block:RebloggedFrom}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Not with just editing the layout anyway. It's an integral part of the post text, and if you removed it, you would (according to Tumblr etiquette) look like a douche that takes credits for other people's comments/identification of the images.

Your other option is to figure out a way to better style your layout's `blockquote` tags.

Comment: I figured you probably couldn't. You're right. Ok, well how would I be able to make it so that all the "reblogged from" links (if there are multiples like in a post with a lot of replies to it) would be organized and moved, possibly not right above the captions/text?

Comment: I am no advanced css specialist, but I'm going to say right up that it would probably be hard and prone to breaking.